# Cómo manejar los datos de un fichero?

Tags: c++, filesystem

necesito saber como a partir de un fichero con un formato como este, extraer los datos y luego crear un fichero de salida que los clasifique según el mes y el primer numero de teléfono y además sumar los costes por mes y para el mismo numero, siguiendo unas pautas para calcular el coste según la duración de la llamada.

fichero entrada:

24/08/2017 111111111 222222222 12:45:34 12:50:23

25/08/2017 333333333 222222222 09:45:34 12:50:23

25/08/2017 111111111 222222222 12:45:23 13:01:30

24/09/2017 111111111 222222222 14:45:34 15:50:23

27/09/2017 111111111 222222222 16:50:21 18:49:23

X

el fichero de salida tiene que ser algo como esto ( se suma los costes dividido en meses y para cada numero):

08/2017 111111111 2.90

08/2017 333333333 4.50

09/2017 111111111 5.50

Esto es lo que tengo ahora, necesito de alguna forma agruparlos por mes y numero, además de calcular el coste, y todo en un archivo de salida. a ver si alguien me da algunos consejos para modificar este código y convertir el fichero de salida como el ejemplo de arriba.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;



int main() {

    string fecha, numOrigen, numDestino, seg2, fecha2 , fecha3 ;
    int mes = 0, hora = 0, min = 0, seg = 0, horaFinal = 0, minFinal = 0, segFinal, segTotal = 0;
    float coste;
    char separador, aux;

    ifstream archivo;

    archivo.open("datos.txt", ios::in);

    if (archivo.is_open()) { //comprobamos si esta abierto.

        archivo >> fecha;

        while (fecha != "X") {

            archivo >> numOrigen >> numDestino >> hora >> separador >> min >> separador >> seg;
            archivo.get(aux);
            archivo >> horaFinal >> separador >> minFinal >> separador;
            getline(archivo, seg2); // los dos valores finales que son los segundos los covierto en un string.
            segFinal = stoi(seg2); // ahora convierto el string en un int.

            if (fecha != "X") {
                ofstream archivo2;

                archivo2.open("coste.txt", ios::app);

                if (archivo2.is_open()) {

                    segTotal = (horaFinal * 3600 + minFinal * 60 + segFinal) - (hora * 3600 + min * 60 + seg); //calculo la duracion de la llamada en segundos.

                    if (segTotal <= 60) {
                        coste = segTotal * 0.01 + 0.5;

                    }
                    else if (segTotal > 60 && segTotal < 120) {
                        segTotal -= 60;
                        coste = 60 * 0.01 + segTotal * 0.005 + 0.5;

                    }
                    else if (segTotal >= 120) {
                        segTotal -= 120;
                        coste = 60 * 0.01 + 60 * 0.005 + segTotal * 0.001 + 0.5;

                    }

                    archivo2 << fecha << " " << numOrigen << " " << numDestino << " " << fixed << setprecision(2) << coste << "\n";
                }
                else {
                    cout << " Error, No se ha podido abrir el archivo.";

                }

                archivo >> fecha;
            }

        }
        archivo.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error, no se pudo abrir el archivo.";

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: y que probaste hacer?

Comment: estoy pensando que de alguna forma(que no se como) comparar los meses cuando se lee en el archivo, si coincide el mes pues procederia a leer el numero, y si es el mismo numero, pues que sumaria el coste , pero la verdad es que estoy perdido, ya que se tendria que ir leyendo y comparando al mismo tiempo.

Comment: con un paso a la vez, despues lo mejoras. Pero tenes que agregar codigo y preguntar algo que no te sale.

Comment: okay, me pondré a ello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que no entiendo del todo cual es la pregunta real que haces, pero parece ser que tu problema no está en la lectura de datos ni en los cálculos, únicamente quieres encontrar una forma de agruparlos.

Para agrupar datos hay muchas formas de realizarlo, la mas correcta sería haciendo clases para que todo se encuentre correctamente jerarquizado, pero también puede usar la estructura "map" o "dictionary" como le llaman en python. Esto lo que te dejará es tener listas de datos agrupados por X o Y cosa.
Supongamos que te dan una lista de Nombre, Genero y Ciudad, y luego deberás imprimir los grupos con el mismo genero y las mismas ciudades.

```
Fabian M Monterrey
Julia F Cordoba
Alan M Cordoba
Elizabeth F Lima
Kate F Lima
```

Con ello puedes hacer maps para agruparlos.

```cpp
int main(){
    string nombre, genero, ciudad;
    map<string,vector<string>> mismoGenero;
    map<string,vector<string>> mismaCiudad;

    while(cin >> nombre >> genero >> ciudad){
        mismoGenero[genero].push_back(nombre);
        mismaCiudad[ciudad].push_back(nombre);
    }

    cout << "Personas con el mismo Genero" << endl;
    for(auto par:mismoGenero){
        cout << "Genero " << par.first << ": " << endl;
        for(auto nom:par.second){
            cout << nom << endl;
        }
    }


    cout << "Personas de la misma ciudad" << endl;
    for(auto par:mismaCiudad){
        cout << "Ciudad " << par.first << ": " << endl;
        for(auto nom:par.second){
            cout << nom << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Con ello obtendrás una salida de datos agrupados

```
Personas con el mismo Genero

Genero F: Julia, Elizabeth, Kate
Genero M: Fabian, Alan

Personas de la misma ciudad
Ciudad Cordoba: Julia, Alan
Ciudad Lima: Elizabeth, Kate
Ciudad Monterrey: Fabian
```

Puedes utilizar esta misma técnica para agrupar tus datos por Numero Telefonico y luego por Mes o a la inversa. Igualmente puedes tener maps dentro de maps, y si necesitas de datos que no se repitan puedes sustituir un map de vectores por un set que mantiene todos sus datos únicos.

No olvides agregar las librerías de map y vector.